# Как лучше распараллелить задачу?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день!
Есть задача, которую хотелось бы распараллелить.
Имеются функции

```
y1 = F1(x1, x2, ..., xn),  
y2 = F2(x1, x2, ..., xn)
```

`xi`, `y1`, `y2` - вещественные числа;
`ОДЗ` (область допустимых значений) `F1` явл. подмн. `ОДЗ` `F2`.

***Задача***: перебрать всевозможные наборы (`xi`), вычислить `y1` и `y2`, зафиксировать (записать в файл) набор (`xi`), `y1, y2`, если `|y1 - y2| < e` (разница по модулю меньше заданного e).

---

Выделил следующие функции:
 1. Функция `A` производит перебор наборов `(x1, x2, ..., xn)` для `y1`, является рекурсивной, не представляю как ее можно привести в другой вид;
Вычисление следующего набора занимает времени меньше чем 0.001 (обычно 0.0002) сек.;
 2. Функция `B` - вычисление `y1`, 0.100 - 0.300 сек.;
 3. Функция `C` - вычисление `y2`, может быть двух реализаций: 0.100 - 0.200 сек. или ~1-2 сек. - вторую реализацию скорее всего делать не будем.

Вышеописанные измерения только примерные (просто много раз вызывали методы, мерили при помощи [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ebf7z0sw.aspx) и записывали результат в файл), но описанные диапазоны выдерживают. Измерения производились на `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 760  @ 2.80GHz`.

---

Распараллеливание задачи представляю след. образом:
 1. главный поток - выполняет `A`, результаты складывает в общую для потоков очередь;
 2. функция `P` - берет очередной набор из очереди, вычисляет `y1, y2`, сравнивает разницу, записывает в файл при необходимости;
 3. функцию `P` запустить в нескольких потоках.

---

Реализация функций `A, B, C` уже есть на C#.
С потоками знаком только на `WinAPI`, прочитал статью на RSDN [Работа с потоками в C#](http://rsdn.org/?summary/4512.xml). Есть некоторые представления, про распараллеливание, но хотелось бы добиться максимальной производительности, т.к. по нашим подсчетам количество всевозможных (`xi`) больше 10e+9.

*Прошу в примерах показать возможные способы распараллеливания.*

**UPD**
Опечатка: количество всевозможных (`xi`) больше 10e+9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать [producer-consumer pattern](/q/428327)?

Поскольку функции `B` и `C` сами по себе быстрые, нужно распараллелить лишь различные вызовы этих функций.

Можно сделать так:

1. Поток №1 (producer) вычисляет последовательность наборов `x1, x2, ..., xn`, используя функцию `A`. Если вычисление можно распараллелить, вместо потока появляется группа потоков. Результаты складываются в очередь, откуда...
2. Группа потоков №2 (consumer) получает задания из очереди, выполняет для этого набора переменных функцию `P`, которая вычисляет `B`, `C` и сравнивает результаты. Если разность достаточно мала, результат уходит в следующую очередь (для неё текущий поток — producer), откуда...
3. Поток №3 читает данные из очереди и записывает их в файл.

Поскольку узким местом, по идее, является вычисление `P`, количество потоков в группе №2 следует сделать равным количеству ядер в системе.

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо! Пока разбираюсь.

Comment: @ildar: в исследовании нужный пример кода расположен в самом конце. Часть про C можно не читать :-)

Comment: Только нужно убедиться, что producer-ы работают (в целом) медленнее consumer-ов. Иначе очередь будет слишком длинной.

Или использовать очередь с ограничением количества элементов в ней, тогда система будет самосинхронизироваться.
(что-то такое я писал в своем последнем комментарии к этому исследованию (правда, примеры на Си)).

Comment: @avp: кстати, да, спасибо за обновление в исследовании! на выходных разберусь с ним и добавлю в текст.

Comment: Способ работает на ура! Сделал как описано в [исследовании](http://hashcode.ru/research/221526/многопоточность-имплементация-producer-consumer-pattern) с использованием класса `BlockingCollection`, что очень упрощает реализацию. Но метод [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd460688) кажется проще.

Comment: Использовал этот способ, т.к., в данном случаи он больше подходит.

Answer (score 6):

- Могу предложить следующий *quick-and-dirty* вариант с использованием [Parallel LINQ.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd460688)

> - Вычисление `Y1(arguments)`, `Y2(arguments)` и дельты между ними имеет смысл  синхронно производить в конструкторе класса `Result.` Параллелить их выполнение для заданного набора аргументов, а затем как-то reduc'ить результаты кажется мне *нецелесообразным.*
> - Если реализация вашей функции `A` не укладывается в логику `Range().Select(),` то ее стоит переписать с использованием `yield return new Arguments(...)` и подставить вместо генератора, который приведен в моем примере.
> - Обратите внимание [на место, в котором вызывается `AsParallel().`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014460/c-asparallel-does-order-matter)

- В *production* варианте, наверно, стоит отделить вычисление результатов от их форматирования и записи в файл.

  ```
  var results = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
                          .AsParallel()
                          .Select(i => new Arguments(i))
                          .Select(arguments => new Result(arguments))
                          .Where(result => result.Delta < Epsilon)
                          .Select(result => result.ToString());

  File.WriteAllLines(path, results);
  ```

Comment: Думаю, `.AsOrdered` автору не нужно, он ведь вычисляет по существу множество.

Comment: @VladD Да, порядок вычисления здесь не действительно не важен, а даже если в итоге результат нужен в отсортированном виде, правильнее делать `ordering` уже в самом конце. Исправил ответ, спасибо.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, спасибо! Функция `A` не укладывается в логику `Range().Select()` и ее можно переписать с использованием `yield return new Arguments(...)`. Порядок не важен.